# Можно ли заменить EJB бины на CDI?

Tags: java, ejb

Можно ли заменить `EJB` бины на `CDI` и как это скажется на работе программы?

В крайнем случае, можно ли заменить как-то аннотации (оставить только `@Inject` или `@EJB`), к примеру [тут](https://github.com/RustemRiz/AiNovus)?

UserBean.java:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
private User user;  
@EJB
private UserManager userManager;

boolean doLogin(String login, int passwordHash) {
    user = userManager.doLogin(login, passwordHash);
    if (logUser == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        user = logUser;
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("greetings");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

UserManager.java:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserManager {
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "examplePU")
     private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User doLogin(String login, int passwordHash) {
        UserEntity userEntity = entityManager.find(UserEntity.class, login);
        return userEntity.toDto();
    }

    public User createUser(String login, int passwordHash){
        UserEntity newUserEntity = new UserEntity();
        newUserEntity.setName(login);
        newUserEntity.setPasswordHashCode(passwordHash);
        entityManager.persist(newUserEntity);
        return newUserEntity.toDto();
    }

    public void updateUser(User user){       
        UserEntity userEntity = entityManager.find(UserEntity.class, user.getName());                
        userEntity.fromDto(user);
        entityManager.merge(userEntity);
    }
}
```

RegistrationBean.java:

```
@Named 
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationBean {

    private String newLogin = "";
    private String newPassword = "";
    @EJB
    private UserManager userManager;
    @Inject
    private UserBean userBean;

    public void register() {
        newLogin = newLogin.trim();
        User newUser = userManager.createUser(newLogin, newPassword.hashCode());
        userBean.doLogin(newUser.getName(), newPassword.hashCode());
        }
    }

}
```

Когда я меняю аннотацию @EJB на @Inject, бросает ошибку:

```
20:38:22,150 ERROR [ru.rustem.servlets.ErrorHandler] (default task-1) ERRORServlet : greetingsServlet Code :500Message:Can not set ru.rustem.ejb.UserManager field ru.rustem.beans.UserBean.userManager to ru.rustem.ejb.UserManager$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$Exception : class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
20:38:24,402 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /view/: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ru.rustem.ejb.UserManager field ru.rustem.beans.UserBean.userManager to ru.rustem.ejb.UserManager$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
```

Задача в том чтобы отставить только один тип бинов или хотя бы аннотаций...

Comment: Вы неплохо управляетесь с редактором ;) Если Вам удобно, можете заменить *<br>* двойным Enter (т. е. оставить пустую строку между абзацами). Удачи в сообществе!